# Dumping json5 file without quotation marks

Tags: json

I have the below data in json5

```
annotations: [
        {
            uuid: "dcf06036-0af1-4ee6-86d1-aa5a66a68dff",
            title: "crane",
            description: "crane",
            position: ["313902.932, 5158154.597, 478.023"],
            offset: [
                0,
                0,
                0,
            ],
            children: [],
            cameraPosition: [
                "313888.198, 5158135.226, 481.088",
            ],
            cameraTarget: [
                "313900.083, 5158155.900, 472.458",
            ],
        },
```

i need to save the list in position like so without quotation marks.

```
position: [313902.932, 5158154.597, 478.023],
```

However json5.dump always saves them with quotation marks. How do i save them without quotation marks? The api that reads the json5 file cant work with the quotations in them.

i tried .strip and .replace, none of them work because when the function json5.dump runs, it always add the quotation marks for the properties.

Edit Solution:
The problem was that the json elements was fetched from somewhere and it is not in the data type it is supposed to be, here is the solution.

```
position = str(session.get("position"))
position_ls = [float(value) for value in position.split(', ')]
```

Take them as the data type it came in, the convert it into float and into a list.

Comment: You're making the classic newbie mistake of thinking in terms of what text looks like instead of what it represents. `["313902.932, 5158154.597, 478.023"]` is a 1-element array with a single string inside, where the string contains comma-separated textual representations of numbers. What you want is a 3-element array whose elements are numbers. The operation you need isn't "remove the quotation marks"; it's "parse a comma-delimited string", or perhaps you need to *remove* a previous operation that produced this string in the first place.

Comment: Also, you need to specify the language you're working with. I'm guessing Python, because `dump` sounds like Python, but we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: Yes, this is python, should have specify it down. My bad. 
I solved the problem now and it is posted as the solution.